# Create RSS flow based on new topics in a phpbb forum

Tags: rss, phpbb

I want to be able to create a RSS flow based on the new topics that are created in a phpbb forum.
This forum has no rss subscription available and I'm not the owner of the forum so I cannot modify/add rss flow in the settings.

I already tried with http://createfeed.fivefilters.org/ and with a Yahoo pipe, I get the topics names great in the RSS flow.
My problem is that the same topics are coming again and again, several times a day.

Any idea how I can do to have only the NEW topics and/or messages ?

The forum in question is http://www.chartemontsdor.fr/viewforum.php?f=14&sid=5f9086b668372b8d9dc90210cfc15d3f

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to contact the forum admin and ask them to enable the Atom feed for the forum, which comes built into phpBB.

Comment: I already contacted the admin but he doesn't want to enable the rss feed. And I think I'm the only one who needs it. It is a small forum, and the admin is not an IT expert...